# Why does std::function accept a this reference in the signature?

Tags: c++, function, this

Member functions have an implicit `this` pointer parameter. Why does `std::function` accept this signature, then, where S is a simple class? ([complete sample](http://liveworkspace.org/code/aec1faad3eb51c99acc333ed63664434))

```
std::function<void(S &)> func = &S::foo;
```

Calling it works, too, and distinguishes objects:

```
S s1 = {5};
S s2 = {6};

func(s1); //prints 5
func(s2); //prints 6
```

What I'd normally expect is that it needs a pointer, which works as well: ([complete sample](http://liveworkspace.org/code/a74d103816d0f3c261e8b3d501d95b00))

```
std::function<void(S * const)> func = &S::foo;

S s1 = {5};
S s2 = {6};

func(&s1); //prints 5
func(&s2); //prints 6
```

Why does the first one work when I pass a reference into the member function when the implicit `this` parameter is a pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::function<SIG>` can be constructed from many things that behave like functions, converting them to an appropriate `std::function` object.

In this case `void S::foo()` behaves much like a function `void foo_x(S&)` (as in they both require an `S` to call, and potentially modify `S`, returning nothing). Consequently `std::function<void(S&)>` provides a constructor for converting the member function into a function object. I.e.

```
std::function<void(S &)> func = &S::foo;
```

uses a constructor, something like `std::function<void(S&)>( void(S::)() )`, to create something equivalent to:

```
void foo_x(S & s ) { return s.foo(); }
std::function<void(S&)> func = foo_x;
```

Similarly,

```
std::function<void(S * const)> func = &S::foo;
```

is equivalent to

```
void foo_x(S * const s ) { return s->foo(); }
std::function<void(S* const )> func = foo_x;
```

through a constructor like `std::function<void(S* const )>( void(S::)() )`.

Comment: That was a very informative read, thanks. It makes a lot more sense when you consider that `std::function` is independent of raw function pointers and has the power to do what it likes to increase usabilty of the thing it's wrapping.

Answer (score 5):

Because `std::function` is correctly designed.  The fact that `this` is a pointer is an accident of history and a detail internal to the member function. The fact should have no impact on the design decisions of users of the function.

The designers of `std::function` decided, rightly, to accept member functions when the first parameter  type in the signature is a reference.